# Convergence of series of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to solve exercise I.2.3f) in the book by [Elstrodt](https://books.google.de/books?id=5ugfBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false). I have solved all the other exercise up to this one, so we can use their results.

[image]

Translation:

f) Consider the abelian group $(\mathfrak{B}(X),\Delta)$. Then the series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ converges (defined as the convergence of the sequence of partial sums $A_1 \Delta A_2 \Delta ... \Delta A_n$) if and only if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n = \emptyset$.
The book uses the following definitions for the lim sup, lim inf and lim:

> Definition:
>
> Let $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of subsets of $X$, then
>
> $\varlimsup \limits_{n \to \infty} := \{x \in X: x \in A_n \text{ for infinitely many } n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
>
> is the limit superior and
>
> $\varliminf \limits_{n \to \infty} := \{x \in X: \text{ There is an }n_0(x) \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } x \in A_n \text{ for all} n \geq n_0(x)\}$
>
> is the limit inferior of the sequence $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$.
>
> The sequence $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is convergent if $\varliminf \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n = \varlimsup \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n$. In this case the limit is defined as
>
> $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n := \varliminf \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n = \varlimsup \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n$
>
> and we say the sequence $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ converges to $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n$.

The forward direction of the exercise is the term test for series familiar from real sequences, but since the limit is not defined in terms of a metric I don't know how to start. I need to prove that $\varliminf \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n = \varlimsup \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n = \emptyset$ and in fact it is enough to show that $\varlimsup \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n = \emptyset$ since
$\varliminf \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n \subset \varlimsup \limits_{n \to \infty} A_n$.

I thought that we might be able to use exercise 2.2, which states that a sequence of subsets of $X$ converges to $\emptyset$ if and only if for every $x \in X$ there are only finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in A_n$.

I would appreciate any help or hints.

Thank you!

Comment: Define $(\mathfrak{B}(X),\Delta)$ as a *group*. I am used to seeing a similar notation but for a *metric space*, the Nikodym metric space, where $\Delta$ denotes symmetric difference

Comment: @FShrike Yes, $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference here as well.

Comment: I apologise for leaving full solutions earlier. Hopefully you didn't see them! The solutions are now hidden behind spoilers, with hints, as you requested

Comment: @FShrike Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I found these to be odd definitions, but it made for an interesting problem

Comment: @FShrike Yeah, I don't know why the book defines it this way. I feel like the expressions using unions and intersections are more natural. Do you think it is easier to prove from those? I left them out to not make my post too long. In the other exercises I sometimes used them instead.

Comment: Well, all the unions and intersections that would be involved in an expression like $A_1\Delta A_2\Delta A_3\Delta A_4\Delta A_5$ are already quite horrible to write out explicitly. $\Delta$ serves as a compact notation: I just feel like "a series of sets" is a bizarre notion. I've studied measure theory to a decent level without coming across such things, but I'm sure the book finds a use for it

Comment: @FShrike Oh, I thought you were talking about the definitions of lim sup and lim inf. I think this exercise is just for the fun of it. I don't think it is necessary to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Delta_{k=1}^nA_k$ denote a "partial sum", $A_1\Delta A_2\Delta\cdots\Delta A_n$.

I partially solve the first one here, and leave the solutions to the rest of the first implication and to the whole of the second behind a spoiler, as you asked for hints only.

> Begin with the assumption that $\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n=\emptyset$.
>
> $\sum_{k\ge1}A_k$ fails to converge iff. there exists an $x\in\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}\Delta_{k=1}^nA_k\setminus\underline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}\Delta_{k=1}^nA_k$, since $\underline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}\subseteq\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}$ is obvious.
>
> This means that although there is a strictly increasing sequence $\{n_m\}_{m\in\Bbb N}$ with $x\in\Delta_{k=1}^{n_m}A_k$ for each $m$, for every $n_m$ there exists a $\lambda_m\gt n_m$ such that $x\notin\Delta_{k=1}^{\lambda_m}A_k$. We can choose $\lambda_m$ such that it is the *smallest* such integer. This means that $x\in\Delta_{k=1}^{\lambda_m-1}A_k$; by the associativity of symmetric difference: $$\Delta_{k=1}^{\lambda_m}A_k=(A_{\lambda_m}\setminus\Delta_{k=1}^{\lambda_m-1})\sqcup(\Delta_{k=1}^{\lambda_m-1}A_k\setminus A_{\lambda_m})$$

Hint: In order to contradict $\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n=\emptyset$, we want to show $x$ is in infinitely many of the $A_n$. What does the above equation imply (in context) about where $x$ is?

> So the conditions on $x$ imply that $x\in A_{\lambda_m}$ (they imply more actually, that $x\in A_{\lambda_m}\cap\Delta_{k=1}^{\lambda_m-1}A_k$).
>
>  By taking a subsequence and relabelling (removing all repeated values) we have a strictly increasing sequence $\{\lambda_m\}_{m\in\Bbb N}$ for which $x\in A_{\lambda_m}$ for every $m$. It follows that $x\in\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n$, which contradicts the hypothesis that this "limit superior" is empty. Therefore no such $x$ exists, and the "series converges".

An extremely similar, backward argument proves the other implication. Associativity of symmetric difference is the key player (imo) in both arguments. A solution to the other implication is given below.

Hint: We want to use convergence of the "series" to show that there cannot exist an $x$ in the limit superior of $(A_n)$. This means we want to show such $x$ belong to certain tails of the "partial sums", and use convergence to arrive at a contradiction.

> Now let's suppose that $\underline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}\Delta_{k=1}^nA_k=\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}\Delta_{k=1}^nA_k$.
>
>  $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n\neq\emptyset$ iff. there exists an $x\in\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n$. Take this $x$, and take an associated strictly increasing sequence $\{n_m\}_{m\in\Bbb N}$ for which $x\in A_{n_m}$ for all $m$. If, for some $m$, $x\notin\Delta_{k=1}^{n_m-1}A_k$, then $x\in A_{n_m}\setminus\Delta_{k=1}^{n_m-1}A_k$ so in particular $x\in\Delta_{k=1}^{n_m}A_k$, therefore $x$ is always in exactly one of the $n_m-1,n_m$th "partial sums". We can then take a strictly increasing sequence $\{\lambda_m\}_{m\in\Bbb N}$ with $x\in\Delta_{k=1}^{\lambda_m}A_k$ for all $m$, by suitable choices of $\lambda_m\in\{n_m-1,n_m\}$.
>
>  By hypothesis, this is sufficient to claim that there exists an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ with $x\in\Delta_{k=1}^nA_k$ for all $n\ge n_0$. For such $n$, we have: $$x\in\Delta_{k=1}^nA_k\text{ and }x\in (A_{n+1}\setminus\Delta_{k=1}^nA_k)\sqcup(\Delta_{k=1}^nA_k\setminus A_{n+1})$$Which together imply that $x\notin A_{n+1}$. We then have that $x\notin A_n$ for all $n\ge n_0+1$.
>
>  This contradicts the assertion that $x\in A_{n_m}$ for all $m$, since this is not true for all $m$ such that $n_m\gt n_0$ (and such $m$ must exist, since the sequence was taken strictly increasing). Then no such $x$ exists, and we have that $\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}A_n=\emptyset$.

Comment: I've now worked through your full answer and there are still a few things I don't fully understand. It's clear why $x \in \Delta_{k=1}^{n_m}$ if $x \notin \Delta_{k=1}^{n_{m} - 1}$. But if $x \in \Delta_{k=1}^{n_{m} - 1}$, then $x \notin \Delta_{k=1}^{n_m}$, right? So it is in exactly one of the $n_m -1$, $n_m$th "partial sums" but not both. This fact then ensures that $x \in \Delta_{k=1}^n$ for infintely many $n$ since there are infinitely many $n$ such that $x \in A_n$ and we know $x$ is in the partial sum up to $n$ or the previous one, correct?

Comment: @DerivativesGuy You are correct that I spoke incorrectly when I added “(or both)” to the sentence - I hadn’t actually checked! The key conclusion is that for some choice of $\lambda_m\in\{n_m-1,n_m\}$, $x\in\Delta_{k=1}^{\lambda_m}$. We can then take the strictly increasing infinite sequence of $\{n_m\}$ and turn that into a strictly increasing infinite sequence $\{\lambda_m\}$. We then get to say that $x\in\overline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}\Delta_{k=1}n$, but by hypothesis this is equivalent to $x\in\underline{\lim}_{n\to\infty}\Delta_{k=1}^n$.

Comment: So yes, your comment is correct! I just replied with the notation of my post to be clear.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It would be great if you could edit your post accordingly. I also think the induction argument is unnecessary since we can just use your argument for any arbitrary $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy Minor edits made. I’ve removed the “by an easy induction” remark since you’re right: the induction is so easy it isn’t really an induction (or not needed to be) at all. It was how I conceived of it at the time. If you want clarification on anything further, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, looks good now! I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @DerivativesGuy Thank you. You’re very welcome

Comment: @DerivativesGuy A more intuitive (and relevant) notion of set convergence can be found in “the Nikodym metric space”, if you want to dig a little into that